# How to make a conditional statement on wordpress for posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have this code:

```
   <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "<div class='menu_map_cta'>";} else { echo "<div class='view_map'>"; } ?>
    See the Flight Path
 <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "</div>";} else { echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

Basically the above statement is to change the class of a div per each page... But I want it to show `"div class="view_map">` when viewing ALL Posts too. The above statement is only to show the one div on the front page (Page 24)

I can hide it on ALL posts, but I'd rather just use the one div on all posts too.

```
   <li id="menu-item-1640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
   <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "<div class='menu_map_cta'>";} else { echo "<div class='view_map'>"; } ?>
        <?php if(!is_single()): ?>See the Flight Path<?php endif; ?>
     <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "</div>";} else { echo "</div>"; } ?>
    </li>
```

Comment: *"exclude posts from viewing certain divs"*...What does that mean?

Comment: Please clarify your question, its not really clear what you want to do. Also, the second if block is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry @Steve ... Basically the above statement is to change the class of a div per each page... But I want it to show "div class="view_map"> when viewing ALL Posts too. The above statement is only to show the one div on the front page (Page 24) 

I can hide it on ALL posts, but I'd rather just use the one div on all posts too.

Comment: Sorry @Mevius -                        <li id="menu-item-1640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
                       <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "<div class='menu_map_cta'>";} else { echo "<div class='view_map'>"; } ?>
                         <?php if(!is_single()): ?>See the Flight Path<?php endif; ?>
                         <?php if ( is_page( 24 ) ) {echo "</div>";} else { echo "</div>"; } ?>
                        </li>

Comment: OK Dan, well the code snippet you have posted should set the class to `view_map` on every page of the site except for p24 (homepage), so that covers post pages also doesnt it? Probably i have still not fully understood

Comment: You'd of thought so - but apparently that's not how it's functioning right now :(.... Maybe there is something else in my code which is stopping this from working on posts?

Comment: @Steve - apologies for initial poor explanation!

Comment: @DanHawkins No need to apologise. Well that is what the code does, its pretty simple, so i cant see how it would fail. Perhaps this snippet is in a file that doesnt get called for posts (eg its in page.php or similar)

Comment: Just to clarify, currently you are seeing `div class='menu_map_cta'>` on post pages as well as home, but you want to see `div class='view_map'>` on post pages. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Steve - not quite :), I want to display 'menu_map_cta' on the front page... and 'view_map' on the sub-pages... But I also want to show 'view_map' on posts too and not 'menu_map_cta' which is what currently shows on posts.

Comment: Got it, well i can only guess as i said above, that the above codesnippet isnt being run on posts. Without digging into the theme myself its really hard to help any further im afraid

Comment: @Steve - many thanks for replying and helping anyway! All the best :)